# Extract numbers from an iframe in Matlab

Tags: matlab, iframe

I want to extract some statistics of soccer and I came across soccerway.

The problem is that there is some statistics in an `iframe`

Example url:
    http://pt.soccerway.com/matches/2014/09/20/spain/primera-division/club-atletico-de-madrid/real-club-celta-de-vigo/1821403/?ICID=PL_MS_04

The html code resuting of the area is:

```
<h2>General Game Stats Chart</h2>


<div class="content  ">
  <div class="block_match_stats_plus_chart real-content clearfix " id="page_match_1_block_match_stats_plus_chart_10">

  <iframe src="./Almería vs. Villarreal - 19 Agosto 2013 - Soccerway_files/saved_resource.html" style="width: 550px; height: 300px; overflow-y: hidden;" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

The part corresponding to what I want is:[image]

All I want is the numbers. any suggestions to work around this?

My idea is to save it as a picture and then use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18169-optical-character-recognition--ocr-) from file exchange but I don't know how to save it as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the HTML code of the URL in your question, you'll see that figure is generated by the following part:

> `<iframe src='/charts/statsplus/1821403/' style='width: 550px; height: 300px; overflow-y: hidden;' frameborder='no' allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"> </iframe>`

So all you have to do is save that file, using its full URL:

> `http://pt.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/1821403/`

The obtained file is HTML, not an image file. Thus you can extract the numbers directly (no need for optical character recognition). Just save it as follows

```
urlwrite('http://pt.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/1821403/','file.html')
```

and then you can parse the obtained `file.html` to get the numbers. For example, the numbers for Cantos (corner kicks) are in this part:

> `<tr>
>      <td class='legend left value'>6</td>
>      <td colspan='4' class='legend title'>Cantos</td>
>      <td class='legend right value'>3</td>
>   </tr>`

As you can see, `'legend left value'` contains 6 (number corresponding to left team, Atlético de Madrid) and `'legend right value'` contains 3 (right team, Celta de Vigo):